# pass previous command's arguments to current command

Tags: linux, bash, parameters

There are times when I want to take the previous command's parameters and apply them to the current command.

Here is an example

```
$ cat foo.txt
$ vim foo.txt
```

I'd like to find a shortcut to not have to type out vim foo.txt

Comment: Those aren't *arguments*, but the *output*, that you're looking for, since `~/foo.txt` is printed by `locate`.

Comment: @grawity you are completely right. I modified the question because it made no sense the way I asked it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I often use the Bash command `yank-last-arg`, shortcut `M-.` or `Esc`+`.`. This copies the last argument from the previous history entry into the current line at the current position, so you can check and edit the argument.

Comment: Plus 1 for esc .

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to use `!$`

example:

```
vim !$
```

To grab the last parameter in the last command, use `!foo:$ as shown below

```
cp foo bar
!cp:$ foobar
#This will copy foo to bar, and then bar to foobar
```

You could alternativly use the following syntax

```
cp foo bar
!!:$
```

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/08/bash-history-expansion/

Comment: Be aware, `!$` only expands to the last argument, not all. And this does not answer your question as stated—do you want command substitution as in `vim "$(locate foo.txt)"`?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Since there are no answers yet, I am going to clarify the question.

Comment: To take *all* the parameters, use `!*` -- http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#History-Interaction